# Independence of solutions (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider

$$x'=\begin{pmatrix}0&&1\\1/t^2&&-1/t\end{pmatrix}x$$

$x=(t,1)^T$ is a solution for this ODE. Using d'Alembert's formula I found another solution: $x=(-\frac{1}{2t},\frac{1}{2t^2})^T$.

> I want to verify that these solutiuons are indeed linearly independent.

According to my script it is sufficient to show that they are independent at one single $t$.

If I choose $t=1$, I get $(1,1)^T$ and $(-1/2,1/2)^T$ which are clearly independent. Is that everything or am I doing something wrong?

Furthermore, how does the Wronskian look like?

$$W(t)=\begin{pmatrix}t&&-\frac{1}{2t}\\1&&\frac{1}{2t^2}\end{pmatrix}$$
, so $det (W(t))=\frac{1}{t}$?

So finding a $t$ such that $det(W(t))\neq 0$, would also be a method to show that my solutions are linearly independent?

Comment: The wronskian is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Yes your solutions are linearly independent and your proof is correct.